# How to save and load tflite version of posenet in react-native?

Tags: react-native, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

How to save and load `tflite` version of `posenet` in react native?
Would it make a change in real time pose estimation in react native? In my case the model is loaded from the server and it takes 15 or more seconds to estimate the keypoints from the loaded model. Then I tried to use the tflite version of TensorFlow so that the estimation time would be reduced. I used [tflite-react-native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tflite-react-native). But it seems to be not working.

Can anyone give me a suggestion for a good way for integrating tflite in react-native? Or should I try bridging for this feature?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React Native why not just use the PoseNet model that comes with `Tensorflow.js` instead? You can download the model weights and the json file from `Tensorflow Hub` then use them offline, for example this [link](https://tfhub.dev/s?deployment-format=tfjs&q=posenet) shows all the models available for PoseNet. I would use the MobileNet version that has already been quantized for you which is [this one](https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/tfjs-model/posenet/mobilenet/quantized/1/100/1/default/1).

This should give you a zip file which contains the following:

```
./
|-- group1-shard1of1
|-- group1-shard1of1.bin
|-- model-stride16.json 
`-- model-stride8.json
```

Then just load in the PoseNet model from the client and pass in the paths to the model weights and model bin file as the model you want to use:

```
import * as posenet from '@tensorflow-models/posenet'
import {
  bundleResourceIO
} from "@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native";

// change the paths 
const modelJson = require('model-stride16.json');
const modelWeights = require('group1-shard1of1.bin');

const net = await posenet.load({
  modelUrl: bundleResourceIO(modelJson, modelWeights)
});

const predictions = await net.estimateSinglePose(imageTensor)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Surely I'll try that one . Should I update ```metro.config.js``` file ? Can you share an example how you draw the skeleton over the camera with the 17 keypoints?

Comment: You don't need to and you should ask a new question for that. If my answer helps please accept and upvote it.